# Trying to implement a manual trigger for infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, triggers, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to add, essentially, a "load more posts" element to Paul Irish's infinite scroll, and no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to generate, though infinite scroll works by itself.

My markup is something like this:

```html
<body>
  <div class="content"/>
  <div id="posts"/>
    <div class="text post"/>
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="load_more">load more</div>
  </div>
<body>
```

and the script I have so far is

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>

        <script>
            $('#posts').infinitescroll({
                navSelector  : "div#paging",            
                nextSelector : "a#next",    
                itemSelector : ".post",
                errorCallback: function(){
                    $('.load_more').hide();
                }
            });
            $(window).unbind('.infscr');
                $('.load_more').click(function(){
                    $('#posts').infinitescroll('retrieve');
                    return false
            });
            
        </script>
```

I have a tooltip script implemented as well, though it didn't have any effect on infinite scroll rendering initially, so honestly I'm not sure why it isn't working. I have a feeling that I'm missing something colossally obvious, but anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks